# MySQL using regex like to find matches between two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with a field casenum (these tables are not from the same system, I'm gathering data from another system and trying to import it into our system). In their table X let's say the casenum is C10972-02 and in our table Y it is 10972. I need to get the id from our table where the casenum is like X.casenum. I can't do where like 'C10972-02' because it's obviously not an exact match.

I'm not sure how to go about this as I'm not too familiar with regexp and MySQL in general. I have a lot of casenums I need to somehow match. Any input helps TIA

Answer (score 1):

REGEXP_LIKE would do the trick

> ```
> CREATE tABLE A(A varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO A VALUES ('C10972-02')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE B(B varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO B VALUES ('10972')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT A.*,B.* FROM A JOIN B ON  REGEXP_LIKE (A.A,B.B)
> ```
>
> ```
> A         | B    
> :-------- | :----
> C10972-02 | 10972
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b9ce2aba407818d43f0ee530e69f6bb)*

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately we're on an older version of MySQL that does not have the regexp_like function. How could I go about it another way?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the equivalent would be REGEXP. ..just realized it was in the comment below. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If the `casenum` in the other table follows a strict format, you can either use wildcards (e.g. `WHERE LIKE '_10972*'`) or [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) in your comparison.

The wildcard `_` matches a single character and the wildcard `*` matches from zero to any number of characters.

Comment: Thank you,! I think I was overcomplicating it